# Деревья Меркле. Проверка "листьев" в ее составе

Tags: алгоритм, хеширование, дерево, blockchain

Читаю интернет и не до конца понимаю одну вещь. Есть Дерево Меркля (или Меркле). Допустим оно имеет N-количество отсортированных "листьев", представляющими блоки данных. Как проверяется, что конкретный "блок" не находится в дереве?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Люди все лайкают, а вот ответа так и нет... Помогите пожалуйста...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проверка принадлежности происходит очень просто - считается хеш блока, а потом просто проверка с хешом во всех листьях. Если есть совпадение, дальше проверяется валидность самого дерева, проходом от этого листа до корня дерева. Например, если это `L2` на вашем рисунке, тогда проверяется `Hash(Hash(0-0), Hash(0-1))`, и дальше корневой хеш: `Hash(Hash(0), Hash(1))`

Свойства криптографических хеш-функций гарантируют, что произведя всего несколько простых вычислений хеша над небольшими объемами данных, мы гарантируем, что этот блок данных действительно входит в хеш в корне дерева.

Можете представить себе, если бы весь блок данных занимал несколько гигабайт, а вам нужно проверить принадлежность небольшой части, допустим 1 мб.

Еще хочу добавить, что операция проверки блока в дереве, это не то, ради чего используют дерево Меркля в blockchain-технологиях. Основное преимущество, это очень быстрый пересчет хеша при поступлении новых данных. А так же быстрый пересчет хеша, при удалении блока данных.

Пример с биткоин. Майнер непрерывно изменяет несколько байт в блоке, и считает хеш, что бы получить хеш начинающийся с множества нулей. В это время приходят новые транзакции, и нужно быстро пересчитать хеш в корне дерева (который является частью блока). Для этого понадобится всего `O(log n)` операций пересчета хеша. Если майнер решил выкинуть транзакцию с блока, и включить другую (с большей комиссией), все так же нужно `O(log n)` пересчетов.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за разъяснение!!!